# How to create a command that only who have one of the roles can use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
let staffrole = ['383874699941117952', '149622819158884353', '149622998180036608'];
```

How do you make a command that only people who have **one of the roles** can use it?
Thank you!

Comment: What have tried to research the documentation on the topic?

Comment: Yes, i tried...

Comment: @Braguetta, I think Daniel was asking what you have tried so far, not just if you have researched the topic. I hope my answer below could help, but if not, please clarify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is that, on a message event, you run the command, and you can check the member's roles for one of the ones in the **array**.

Heres what that would look like:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
    if(command === "whateverItIs") {
        let staffrole = ['383874699941117952', '149622819158884353', '149622998180036608'];
        for(i=0;i<staffrole.length;i++) {
            if(msg.member.roles.filter((role) => role.id == staffrole[i]).size > 0) {
                //run the code
                return;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

On a message event, with the determined `command`,  the bot will check through each of the staff roles and if the `message author` 's roles includes one of the staffrole's then the command will run.

Comment: msg.member.roles.includes is not a function

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing something like this:

First, set your command name in the client's message listener:

```
// ... (in client message listener)
switch(command) {
    case '<your command>':
        runIfRoleIncluded(message);
        break;
}
```

Next, get the role Id from the message that was sent and check if that message's role Id is in your `staffrole` array:

```
function runIfRoleIncluded(message) {
    let rolesCollection = message.member.roles;
    let staffrole = ['383874699941117952', '149622819158884353', '149622998180036608'];

    // only 1 member can send a message, so get role collection's first key (id)
    let messageRoleId = rolesCollection.firstKey();

    // check if message's role id is in staff role array
    if (staffrole.includes(messageRoleId)) {
        // do stuff here
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `.roles` property of the `.member` object is a `Collection`, which is why you have to use the `.firstKey()` method. You can also turn the `Collection` into a normal js `Array`, but the way I outlined above is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Started looking at this... Don't know the discord space very well but got an example bot and with a hello world ping, also found this pretty sweet [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3) that lays out fairly well how to build what amounts to a command switch statement.  Making a lot of guesses here -- *as a note for future questions it would be very helpful for you to add in some code on what you are trying to do* --  a single variable set to an array isn't much to go on...

After Reading what @Raymond Zhang said, because, yeh that's what I was doing...

**this is straight out of the Github gist I linked** ->

```
    ...
      if(command === "kick") {
        if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Administrator","Moderator"].includes(r.name)) )
              return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
     ...
```

I have tested this and it works great, although it checks against the roles name not a number.  It would help if you updated you answer to explain your process.  More info = better answer.  :)

Comment: You're checking against your own bot id

Comment: The IDs that I defined are role IDs, not member IDs.